# wrting to csv file in c++ fails

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

Im working with this code which is supposed to detect faces. The code works totally fine, but as soon as I try to insert three lines for writing to csv file, it breaks down with lengthy error of some 100+ lines -[ERROR FILE LOG](https://gofile.io/d/juzgfp).

This code was taken from :- https://github.com/shunyaos/shunyaface

```
// Header file for Face-Recognition/Detection
#include "shunyaface.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "fstream"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // Create instance of class FaceRec
    std::ofstream filename("test.csv");
    filename<< "TESTING CSV WRITE";

    FaceRec facerec;
    Mat frame;
    Mat frame2;
    clock_t start, end; //This will hold the start and end-time
    int count = 0; //Variable which hold the number of frames elapsed
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    time(&start);
    while(1)
    {
        // Capture a frame          
        cap >> frame;
// Pass the frame to the detect function which will return the frame with a bounding-box on the face and points on the lips and eyes
        frame2 = facerec.detect(frame); 
        count++; //Increment count
        // Display the frame to the user
        imshow("face-detect", frame2);
        if(waitKey(1) == 'q')
            break;
    }
    time(&end); // Stop the time
    cout<< "Output FPS is:"<<count/(end-start)<<endl; //Display Output-FPS
    filename.close();
    return 0;
}
```

So basically as shown above,after inclusion of these lines the code is breaking :-

```
std::ofstream filename("test.csv");
filename<< "TESTING CSV WRITE";
filename.close()
```

Comment: "_it breaks down with lengthy error of some 100+ lines._" Please include said error.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and post it in your question. The link to the error file points to 404 not found. You have a problem with reading CSV. Why do you post code containg opencv? It's not related.

Comment: Try #include <fstream> instead of "fstream".

Comment: @stefan.gal didnt work. error log file : - https://gofile.io/d/juzgfp

Comment: @stefan.gal `<fstream>` instead of `"fstream"` has a little better performance but the compiler will search in all places it would search in former case. With `"fstream"` the compiler will search addionally relative to the source file.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius https://gofile.io/d/juzgfp

Comment: @ThomasSablik https://gofile.io/d/juzgfp  . Code was taken from https://github.com/shunyaos/shunyaface

Comment: Did you forget to end this line `cout<< "In while"<<`? You should try to fix error from top to bottom. The first error is regarding `cout`, `operator<<` and `cv::VideoCapture cap`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ohhh!!!! Please post this as your answer, Ill accept it !!!

Comment: @SunainaChopra Please provide all the necessary information in the question itself, and not in external links.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Apologies Sir. Noted !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to end this line `cout<< "In while"<<`.

Somewhere in your code is this snippet

```
out<< "In while"<<
// Capture a frame
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cap >> frame;
```

You should try to fix error from top to bottom. The first error is regarding `cout`, `operator<<` and `cv::VideoCapture cap`.